# terrain creation using c++ and directx

Tags: c++, directx

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/C++/Series1/tut10.php

***in the tutorial of terrain creation given in the link i am not able to understand the code , basically whats happening in this code***

```
short s_Indices[(WIDTH-1)*(HEIGHT-1)*3];


for (int x=0;x< WIDTH-1;x++){
    for (int y=0; y< HEIGHT-1;y++)    {
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*3+2] = x+y*WIDTH;
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*3+1] = (x+1)+y*WIDTH;
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*3] = (x+1)+(y+1)*WIDTH;
    }
}
```

---

```
short s_Indices[(WIDTH-1)*(HEIGHT-1)*6];


for (int x=0;x< WIDTH-1;x++){
    for (int y=0; y< HEIGHT-1;y++)    {
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+2] = x+y*WIDTH;
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+1] = (x+1)+y*WIDTH;
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6] = (x+1)+(y+1)*WIDTH;

        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+3] = (x+1)+(y+1)*WIDTH;
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+4] = x+y*WIDTH;
        s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+5] = x+(y+1)*WIDTH;
    }
}
```

***what is (x+y***(WIDTH-1))*3+2] and why its equal to  x+y*WIDTH;
this is the code for  creating a 4*3 terrain where z is 0*

can anyone explain the this code briefly to me please , thanks in advance..

Comment: I suggest that you read a book on C++ before you try to use it for graphics programming, so that you at least understand the basic syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's setting up an array of indices that enumerate which vertices to use to draw the geometry.  Each group of 3 indices represent one triangle (as you can see on the page you linked to there's a figure with a set of triangles that illustrates this).

So for example

```
s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*3+2] = x+y*WIDTH;
```

is the bottom-left corner of one such triangle.

and

```
s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*3] = (x+1)+(y+1)*WIDTH;
```

is the top-right corner.

```
            x+1,y+1
          /|
         / |
    x,y /__| x+1,y
```

Comment: and this   s_Indices[(x+y*(WIDTH-1))*6+2] = x+y*WIDTH;  is defining the other series like the top-left ?

Comment: A square consists of two triangles. In the first array (where they multiply by 3) they only define the bottom triangle of each square. In the second array (where they multiply by 6) they define both triangles for each square.

Comment: ohk in first array they just telling how to do it in the 2nd they doing it fully thanks for your reply i appreciate it . it was very help full..